# I want to show the values of two variables in a bar chart using ggplot 2, but cannot figure out how

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a sample code I have written that takes average ride duration for two different customers - members, and casual riders. The problem is that how do I depict these two variables - meanride_member, meanride_casual on a bar chart.

```
install.packages("dplyr")  # Install dplyr package
install.packages("data.table")# Install data.table package
install.packages("janitor")
install.packages("ggplot2")
library('ggplot2')
library('janitor')
library('dplyr')
library("data.table")   
Data1 <- read.csv("Rider_Data_Feb_March.csv")
Data2 <- read.csv("Rider_Data_Jan.csv")
print(nrow(Data1)) #Checking number of rows
print(nrow(Data2)) #Checking number of rows
Data <- rbind(Data1, Data2, use.names = TRUE, Fill = TRUE) #combining two datasets into one
print(nrow(Data)) #verfying if the combining operation was a success
member <- subset(Data, Data$type =="member") #seprating 'member' enteries
casual <- subset(Data, Data$type =="casual") #seprating 'casual' enteries
meanride_member <- mean(member$length, na.rm=TRUE) # single value variable
meanride_casual <- mean(casual$length, na.rm=TRUE) # single value variable
statis <- data.frame(casual= c(meanride_casual, meanride_member), seconds = 1000) # showing seconds so that i have something toi assign either x axis or y axis
ggplot(data = statis) + geom_bar(mapping = aes(y=casual, x=seconds), stat="identity", position = "dodge") # my make shift formula
```

[image: output]

Comment: Your data frame is not tidy because you need information in the column names (the ride type) to plot your graph. `ggplot2`, as part of the tidyverse, expects tidy data. Give it untidy data, and you cause yourself pain. @Corboss has given you one possible solution. Another would be to pivot your data into long format.

Comment: Thanks. His solution is more than i can take for now, I might convert to long if any need arises.